# Practical Common LISP understanding chapter 3

Tags: lambda, lisp, common-lisp, practical-common-lisp

I a looking at the third chapter in [*Practical Common Lisp*](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-simple-database.html). In that chapter one creates a database like application. I am stuck at understanding the `update` function.

I've written the code in my editor and put comments in for my own understanding of the code:

```
(defun update (selector-fn &key title artist rating (ripped NIL ripped-p))
    (setf  ; set ...
        *db*  ; *DB* to ...
        (mapcar  ; the value of the application of ...
            #'(lambda (row)  ; a lambda to rows ...
                (when (funcall selector-fn row)  ; when a row satisfies ...
                    ; (what does funcall do? if I call the selector function
                    ; why do I still have to check for predicates as below?)
                    ; maybe "when a row is selected"? Is WHEN like a loop over rows?
                    (if title (setf (getf row :title) title))  ; the title predicate ...
                    (if artist (setf (getf row :artist) artist))  ; the artist predicate ...
                    (if rating (setf (getf row :rating) rating))  ; the rating predicate ...
                    (if ripped-p (setf (getf row :ripped) ripped)))  ; and the ripped predicate ...
                ; why cannot we use our selector function here instead of repeating stuff?!
                row)  ; why is there a ROW here? isn't the lambda expression already finished?
                ; maybe the WHEN expression does not return anything and this is a return value of the lambda?
            *db*)))  ; applies the lambda to the database
```

Previously a `where` function was given:

```
(defun where (&key title artist rating (ripped NIL ripped-p))
    #'(lambda (cd)
        (and
            (if title (equal (getf cd :title) title) T)
            (if artist (equal (getf cd :artist) artist) T)
            (if rating (equal (getf cd :rating) rating) T)
            (if ripped-p (equal (getf cd :ripped) ripped) T))))
```

As you can see there are some questions for the code presented in the book. I'll list them below again, but leave the comments in, so that it is clearer, what they relate to.

1. At the first glance already this looks like a code duplication. Why can't I somehow use the `where` function, instead of writing all those `if` expressions again?
2. If `funcall` (which is not explained in the book in that chapter for that code ...) really calls the selector function, which is the return value, of a call to the `where` function given, then why do I have to write all those `if` expressions there? Isn't that exactly what the `where` function returns? A selector for those rows, which fit the criteria?
3. Why is there a `row` after the `when` expression, which seemingly belongs to the `lambda` expression? Is that a return value, because the `when` expression doesn't return anything, so that the `lambda` returns the updated row?

I feel like some quite advanced syntax has not been properly explained for this code and I am left guessing how exactly that code works.

An example call to the code would be:

```
(update (where :artist "artist1") :rating 11)
```

I tried that, and it really worked.

Here is my "database":

```
((:TITLE "title3" :ARTIST "artist1" :RATING 10 :RIPPED T)
(:TITLE "title2" :ARTIST "artist2" :RATING 9 :RIPPED T)
(:TITLE "title1" :ARTIST "artist1" :RATING 8 :RIPPED T))
```

And here is the complete code so far:

```
(getf (list :a 1 :b 2 :c 3) :b)

(defvar *db* nil)

(defun make-cd (title artist rating ripped)
    (list :title title :artist artist :rating rating :ripped ripped))

(defun add-record (cd)
    (push cd *db*))

(defun dump-db ()
    (format t "~{~{~a:~10t~a~%~}~%~}" *db*))

(defun prompt-read (prompt)
    (format *query-io* "~a: " prompt)
    (force-output *query-io*)
    (read-line *query-io*))

(defun prompt-for-cd ()
    (make-cd
        (prompt-read "Title")
        (prompt-read "Artist")
        (or (parse-integer (prompt-read "Rating") :junk-allowed t) 0)
        (y-or-n-p "Ripped [y/n]: ")))

(defun add-cds ()
    (loop (add-record (prompt-for-cd))
        (if (not (y-or-n-p "Another? [y/n]: ")) (return))))

(defun save-db (filename)
    (with-open-file
        (out filename :direction :output :if-exists :supersede)  ; this is a list as parameter! not a function call
        ; OUT holds the output stream
        ; opening a file for writing with :DIRECTION :OUTPUT
        ; if it already exists overrite it :IF-EXISTS :SUPERSEDE
        (with-standard-io-syntax (print *db* out))
        ; The macro WITH-STANDARD-IO-SYNTAX ensures that certain variables
        ; that affect the behavior of PRINT are set to their standard values.
    ))

(defun load-db (filename)
    (with-open-file
        (in filename)
        ; IN contains the input stream
        (with-standard-io-syntax (setf *db* (read in)))
        ; file contains standard syntax of lisp
        ; SETF sets the value of *DB* to what is read from IN
        ; WITH-STANDARD-IO-SYNTAX macro ensures that READ is using the same basic
        ; syntax that save-db did when it PRINTed the data.
    ))

(defun select-by-artist (artist)
    (remove-if-not
        #'(lambda (cd) (equal (getf cd :artist) artist))
        *db*))

(defun select (selector-fn)
    (remove-if-not selector-fn *db*))

(load-db "database")
(dump-db)

; not so general selector function
(defun artist-selector (artist)
    #'(lambda (cd) (equal (getf cd :artist) artist)))

; "general" selector function
(defun where (&key title artist rating (ripped NIL ripped-p))
    #'(lambda (cd)
        (and
            (if title (equal (getf cd :title) title) T)
            (if artist (equal (getf cd :artist) artist) T)
            (if rating (equal (getf cd :rating) rating) T)
            (if ripped-p (equal (getf cd :ripped) ripped) T))))

(print (select (where :artist "artist1")))

(defun update (selector-fn &key title artist rating (ripped NIL ripped-p))
    (setf  ; set ...
        *db*  ; *DB* to ...
        (mapcar  ; the value of the application of ...
            #'(lambda (row)  ; a lambda to rows ...
                (when (funcall selector-fn row)  ; when a row satisfies ...
                    ; (what does funcall do? if I call the selector function
                    ; why do I still have to check for predicates as below?)
                    ; maybe "when a row is selected"? Is WHEN like a loop over rows?
                    (if title (setf (getf row :title) title))  ; the title predicate ...
                    (if artist (setf (getf row :artist) artist))  ; the artist predicate ...
                    (if rating (setf (getf row :rating) rating))  ; the rating predicate ...
                    (if ripped-p (setf (getf row :ripped) ripped)))  ; and the ripped predicate ...
                ; why cannot we use our selector function here instead of repeating stuff?!
                row)  ; why is there a ROW here? isn't the lambda expression already finished?
                ; maybe the WHEN expression does not return anything and this is a return value of the lambda?
            *db*)))  ; applies the lambda to the database
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `where` function performs a SQL-like “selection” of the elements by evaluating (with `and`) the different rows:

```
(if title (equal (getf cd :title) title) T)
...
```

to find if a certain “field” has a value specified as parameter to the function. So for instance you can call it with `(where :rating 10 :ripped nil)` as explained in the text.

The `update` function instead perform a SQL-like “update” of one or more fields. And you should note that the body of the anonymous inner function is completely different from the `where` function, since it has lines like:

```
(if title (setf (getf row :title) title))
...
```

These are the lines needed to *update* the “fields”, not to test them. In fact they use `setf`, and not `equal`. So if we draw a parallel with a generic SQL query, the `when` function correspond to the part after the SQL `WHERE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM CDs
WHERE field1 = value1
  AND field2 = value2,
      ...
```

while, in the `update` function, the call to `(funcall selector-fn row)` corresponds to whe `WHERE` part, while the rows `(if ... (setf ...))` corresponds to the `SET` part:

```
UPDATE CDs
SET field1 = value1,
    field2 = value2,
    ...
WHERE field1 = value1
  AND field2 = value2,
      ...
```

For instance, a call like:

```
(update (where :artist "artist1") :rating 11)
```

is equivalent to the SQL query:

```
UPDATE CDs
SET rating = 11
WHERE artist = 'artist1'
```

So, what in your comments inside `update` is called `; the title predicate`, etc. really should be `; the setting of the title`, etc.

So, the answers to your questions are:

1. There is no code duplication, the two set of lines perform two different tasks: in `where` they are used to filter the elements with `equal`, in `update` they are used to set the fields with new values.
2. `(funcall f args)` applies the function `f` to the arguments `args`. So the selector `where` is called for each row to see if it satisfies the predicate *that filters only the rows that must be modified*.
3. The anonymous function inside `update` works in this way: first, if the condition inside the `when` is satisfied, updates the row, by performing an assignment through `setf`. At the end, it returns `row`, that can be modified or not if the `selector-fn` has returned *true* or *false*. So, the update function updates the `*db*` with the values returned by that anonymous function.

Comment: I totally overlooked that there is `setf` instead of `equal` and thought it was the same code all the way. Also I didn't know about the fact that lambdas can return values in common lisp. I only guessed that, because I couldn't find another reason for the `row` being there. Now I know. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, one more question regarding that code: Why cannot I write `(selector-fn row)` instead of `(funcall selector-fn row)`?

Comment: @Zelphir, in Common Lisp you can have compound forms of the type: `(function-name parameters)` or `((lambda (args) body) parameters)`, but not `(function-variable parameters)`, like in Scheme and similar languages. For this reason if you have a variable bound to a function you should use [funcall](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_funcal.htm#funcall) or [apply](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apply.htm#apply). For a discussion about this point, see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp#The_function_namespace) or google "lisp1 vs lisp2".

Comment: I think I get it: funcall "tells" the interpreter to lookup that name in the functions namespace, instead of the variables namespace, where it would not find it, because in Common LISP those two namespaces are separated, while in Scheme it would work, because the namespaces are not separated. It means, that in Scheme you could not have a another variable with the same name as a function's name, but in Common LISP you could.

Comment: @Zelphir, both in Common Lisp and in Scheme you can have named functions (through `defun` in the former and `define` in the latter), and call them in the same way `(name-of-function parameters)`. On the other hand, in both languages you can have a “normal” variable `x` that has as value a function (bounded to it or assigned to it in some way), but while in Scheme you can call the function bounded to `x` as `(x parameters)`, in Common Lisp you have to write `(funcall x parameters)`, since `x` is not the name of a function.